# Angular Firebase: take(1) returns multiple documents

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire

I'm trying to get a single document from the Products collection in Firestore. ProductService handles the query and returns a subscription:

```
//ProductService
export class ProductService {
...  
getByPermalink(permalink: string) {
    return this.db.collection('products', ref => ref.where('permalink','==', permalink ))
      .valueChanges({ idField: 'id' })
      .pipe(take(1)) 
  }
}
```

Then calls it on my component:

```
//ProductComponent
this.productService.getByPermalink(this.permalink).subscribe((res: any) => {
   this.product = res
   console.log('product', this.product)
})
```

All of this works only it doesn't seem to honor the `take(1)` call and returns multiple documents when there are multiple matches to the query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `take(1)` makes it so you only get data one time (as opposed to getting updates over time as the database changes). But that data will contain whatever is returned by your query. If you only want one document, you'll need to restrict the query, not the observable. You can do this with the `limit` function:

```
return this.db
  .collection("products", (ref) =>
    ref.where("permalink", "!=", permalink).limit(1)
  )
  .valueChanges({ idField: "id" })
  .pipe(take(1));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Curious though, why the `take(1)` then if there's already a `limit(1)`?

Comment: Whether to have the `take(1)` depends if you want to keep listening to the database over time. If you just want the data right now and then you want to stop getting data, keep the `take(1)`. If you want to get updates over time as the document changes, then remove it.

Comment: That's really enlightening. Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Upvoted and accepted!